# Why do we never get to see Rex's face in Killer Joe?

Tags: plot-explanation, killer-joe

Not only Rex, but Chris' mother is shown only once and only when she is dead. We never get to see Rex's face.

Is it intentional, maybe so that the audience focuses on main characters only?

Comment: It's based on a play by Tracy Letts. The screenwriter and director decided that the cast of the play was enough to make a movie, and so did not change or add characters.

Comment: I imagine it has to do with the same reason you don't see the monster in some movies. Sometimes the unknown keeps things mysterious and intense.

Comment: To followup on CGCampbells comment: What would've been the benefit? Their 'role' is not important to the story, you can just describe their input to the plot without distracting from the 'strength' of the movie. Actually, adding actors *only* to 'play' the input might have looked as useless filler, since the input is limited to a few facts.